# SQL query with exact value on the table

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress, sql-like

I have a database that records the id in your table as follows: **["10", "19"]**. Must make an appointment to view the results only 10, and only 19. How could make a SQL exibidir to these results?
It could be with LIKE, IN, REGEXP, RLIKE. Recalling that 10 and 19 is figurative, the values can be changed in the query so I can not set these two values.
I tried this way but I can not get the integer value:
Display only one and not the value 10.

```
 $url.= ' AND t.especialidadesaude RLIKE "^['.$especialidadesaude.']" ';
```

Comment: Could you ask your question in a different way? And where do you set $especialidadesaude and to what value do you set it?

Answer (score 0):

Some things are not worth trying in SQL...

Plan A:  Break apart the pieces of info into separate columns or rows as the data is being inserted into the table.

Plan B:  Parse it in your application code after `SELECTing` it.